# How to plot an analysis picture in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to make a plot like this one in MATLAB:

[image]

I searched in google but I did not find any way to do it in MATLAB.
How can I do that figure in MATLAB? Does not need to be exactly the same plot but the same info must be involved in the plot.
Thanks

Comment: What kind of data you have?

Comment: It look more like a diagram, not a true plot, so I don't think that matlab will be the perfect tool for that.

Comment: same info as the plot above ... What you suggest ? Which tool is suitable?

Comment: All kind of presentation program. Of course it's possible to do that with matlab, but, in my opinion, you have better to use a dedicated program.

Comment: Depending on your operating system there are many softwares to do so. Use what you already have, such as PowerPoint or LibreOffice Draw.

Comment: You can even use [Google Drawing](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1V9-Ec-I906-wXpdhpFGCWECJO6lL5qGOsU0vRoXqes0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @EBH God bless you man ,, thank you ,, it is so helpful ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is too long for a comment, so here is a fixed (and without loops) version of @nilZ0r answer (**if you are going to accept any answer, accept his**). I annotated the changes:

```
% Create figure and axes
f = figure('Color',[1 1 1]); clf % <-- white background
a = axes;
aPos = [0.1 0.1 0.03 0.8];
gbColor = [0 1 0.7];
yTick = logspace(4,10,7);
YTickLlb = {'0.01MHz','0.1 MHz','1.0 MHz','10 MHz','100 MHz','1 GHz',''};
set(a,...
    'Position', aPos, ...
    'YAxisLocation','right', ...
    'YLim', yTick([1 end]), ...
    'YScale','log',...
    'YTickLabel',YTickLlb,...
    'XTick',[], ...
    'Box','on',...
    'Color', gbColor)
title('Frequency')

% Plot text
txtFontSize = 12;
txt = {'Hearing threshold (20 kHz)','Therapeutic applications',...
    'Medical imaging','Ultrasound microscopy'};
txtPos = [2e4 1e6 2e7 1e9];
txtOffset = 5;
% No need for a loop:
text(ones(numel(txtPos),1)*txtOffset, txtPos, txt,'FontSize', txtFontSize);

% Plot arrows (with figure as reference)
arrowPos = [[6 70]*1e6; [7 70]*1e8]; % <-- matrix instead of a cell array
% arrowType is deleted
arrowOffset = (aPos(1) + aPos(3)*txtOffset*0.9)*[1 1];
normYTick = linspace(0,1,length(yTick));
% two different calls to 'annotation', based on the arrow type:
annotation(f, 'doublearrow', arrowOffset, interp1(yTick, normYTick,...
    arrowPos(1,:))*aPos(4) + aPos(2),'HeadStyle','Plain','Head1Width',4,...
    'Head2Width',4, 'Head1Length', 4,'Head2Length', 4);
annotation(f, 'arrow', arrowOffset, interp1(yTick, normYTick,...
    arrowPos(2,:))*aPos(4) + aPos(2),'HeadStyle','Plain','HeadWidth',4,...
    'HeadLength',4);

% Plot information text
text(7, yTick(end), '\lambda f = 1500 ms^{-1} in water',...
    'FontSize', txtFontSize)
```

And the result:

[image: Frequency]

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, this is better to do this in some other program (would be easier and better looking). But if you should *do need to do it* in Matlab, something like this would do it.

```
% Create figure and axes
f = figure(1); clf
a = axes;
aPos = [0.1 0.1 0.03 0.8];
gbColor = [0 1 0.7];
yTick = logspace(4,10,7);
YTickLlb = {'0.01Mz','0.1 MHz','1.0 MHz','10 MHz','100 MHz','1 GHz',''};
set(a,...
    'Position', aPos, ...
    'YAxisLocation','right', ...
    'YLim', yTick([1 end]), ...
    'YScale','log',...
    'YTickLabel',YTickLlb,...
    'XTick',[], ...
    'Box','on',...
    'Color', gbColor)
title('Frequency')

% Plot text
txtFontSize = 12;
txt = {'Hearing threshold (20 kHz)','Therapeutic applications','Medical imaging','Ultrasound microscopy'};
txtPos = [2e4 1e6 2e7 1e9];
txtOffset = 5;
for k = 1:length(txt)
    t(k) = text(txtOffset, txtPos(k), txt{k},'FontSize', txtFontSize);
end

% Plot arrows (with figure as reference)
arrowPos = {[6 70]*1e6, [7 70]*1e8};
arrowType = {'doublearrow', 'arrow'};
arrowOffset = (aPos(1) + aPos(3)*txtOffset*0.9)*[1 1];
normYTick = linspace(0,1,length(yTick));
for k = 1:length(arrowPos)
    annotation(f, arrowType{k}, arrowOffset, interp1(yTick, normYTick, arrowPos{k})*aPos(4) + aPos(2),...
        'HeadStyle','Plain','HeadWidth',4, 'HeadLength', 4);
end

% Plot information text
text(7, yTick(end), '\lambda f = 1500 ms^{-1} in water','FontSize', txtFontSize)
```

Comment: This throws an error: _"There is no HeadWidth property on the DoubleEndArrow class"_, there are `Head1Width` and `Head2Width`, and the same for `HeadLength`. But, because `arrowType{k}` mix to different types of arrows, if you simply change these properties it will throw an error on the `Arrow` class.

Comment: @EBH At least for earlier Matlab versions, the propery HeadWidth (or HeadLength) is reinterpreted to Head1Width and Head2With for a double arrow annotation items. So for example by setting `set(h, 'HeadWidth',6)` both `Head1Width` and `Head2Width` would change. But I haven't updated to any of the latest Matlab versions, so perhaps it have changed.

Comment: Well, there is nothing like this mentioned in the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotationdoublearrow-properties.html#property_head1length). BTW I use R2015a. Anyway I upvote for the effort :)

Comment: Probably previously hidden in some the dark, undocumented place. When I probe for *all* properites for the annotation (arrow) handle, `get(get(classhandle(handle(H)),'properties'),'Name')`  Head1Width, Head2Width *and* HeadWidth emerges.